# creating proper array for file input and output to JTextArea

Tags: java, arrays, jtextarea, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

So I am very new to not only java but programming in general.  With that being said I am trying to write a program that creates a calendar based note such that depending on the day chosen you can make a note and put it into a file based on the month and year and then retrieve that and any other note on a day by day basis.  This has to use an array somehow which I do not know how to fully implement being totally confused as to how to work with arrays( tutorials aren't helping).  so here is what I have so far.

First the UserInterface.java file:

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class UserInterface extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private String[] months = {"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};
private String[] days = {"1", "2", "3", "4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"};         
private JButton save, retrieve;
private JTextField year;
private JTextArea entry;
private JComboBox month = new JComboBox(months);
private JComboBox day = new JComboBox(days);

public UserInterface() {


    JPanel mPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
    mPanel.add(new JLabel("Month"));
    mPanel.add(month);
    month.addActionListener(this);

    JPanel dPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
    dPanel.add(new JLabel("Day"));
    dPanel.add(day);
    month.addActionListener(this);

    JPanel yPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
    yPanel.add(new JLabel("Year"));
    yPanel.add(year = new JTextField(4));
    month.addActionListener(this);

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 30, 10));
    p1.add(new JLabel("Set Date for Entry:"));
    p1.add(mPanel);
    p1.add(dPanel);
    p1.add(yPanel);

    JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 60, 10));
    p2.add(save = new JButton("Save"));
    save.addActionListener(this);
    p2.add(retrieve = new JButton("Retrieve"));
    retrieve.addActionListener(this);


    JPanel full = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    full.add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    full.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    full.add(entry = new JTextArea(10, 10), BorderLayout.CENTER);


    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Calendar Manager");
    frame.setSize(500, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable( false );
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(full);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Save")) {

         String m = (String)month.getSelectedItem();

         String d = (String)day.getSelectedItem();
         String y = year.getText();
         String data = entry.getText();

           CalendarManager.save(m, d, y, data);
           entry.setText("Data written successfully to file with name "+ month+" "+year+".txt");

       } else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Retrieve")){



           String m = (String)month.getSelectedItem();

           String d = (String)day.getSelectedItem();
           String y = year.getText();
           String data = "";

           String result = CalendarManager.retrieve(m, d, y, data);
           entry.setText(result);

   }
   }


}
```

then the CalendarManager.java file:

```
import java.io.*;


public class CalendarManager {


private String[] calObject = new String[31];
   public static boolean save(String month, String day, String year, String data) {
   String fileName = month+" "+year+".dat";
   int daynum = Integer.parseInt(day);
   try {
       File file = new File(fileName);
       if(!file.exists()) {
           file.createNewFile();
       } 
       ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
       for(int i=0; i<31; i++){

              output.writeUTF(month+"-"+day+"-"+year+":  "+data);


       }


   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return true;
   }






public static String retrieve(String month, String day, String year, String data) {
   String fileName = month+" "+year+".dat";
   int daynum = Integer.parseInt(day);
   try {
       File file = new File(fileName);
       if(!file.exists()) {
           return "File not found";
       } 
       ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
       for(int i=0; i<31; i++){
          if(input == null){
              return "Entry not found";
          }
          else{

             data = input.readUTF();

          }
       }


   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
return data;



 }
}
```

then finally the CalendarTest.java file:

```
public class CalendarTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   UserInterface calendar = new UserInterface();


}
}
```

If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong and also my code has to be as simple as possible without anything I may not have learned so think beginner's java class material.

Comment: What is the exact problem you're facing here -- where do you need help?

Comment: Your "retrieve" method should be returning an array, not a String, then from there, depending on the day of the month, you would load the text for that day into the JTextArea. Each time the day is changed, you need to take the value from the JTextArea, place the value into the array at the correct position before updating the text for the new day

Comment: Also, JTextArea is a multiline component, meaning Yu need to account for the fact that any given entry may have multiple lines in your file...

Comment: So using code example how would I go about saving the line from the JTextArea into the array and then using another code example how would I then bring it back up because I think that might be all I need to know how to do, or am I wrong and need even more help.

Answer (score 0):

You did not describe what your exact problem is, but after a quick check i guess the file is not saved. Try `String fileName = month+"_"+year+".dat";`
 with an underscore instead of a space.

Comment: 1- You're about attract a bit of negative attention, this should be a comment, yes I know you don't have the rep for it, but there it is; 2- Why would adding "_" into the file name make any difference?

Comment: The file does save although the actual way it was supposed to be done was to create a new directory too but I have no clue how to do that.